# hide the parent div on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the list perspective-list item Blogs,Case_Studies,Whitepapers with respective class.on click the list item it show the respective element in '.page-perspective' ie.If I click blogs it shows only blogs and hide other.If I click whitepapers it shows only whitepapers and hide others.In whitepapers I have four '.page-perspective'.I'm showing only first three element for whitepaper,blogs and casestudy.

I want to hide '.view-row'  but now I'm hiding wrapper section mentioned in code.

```js
(function($) {
  function perspective_type() {
    $(".perspective-list a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".perspective-list a").parent().removeClass('active');
      $('.wrapper .page-perspective').slice(0,3).show();
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.wrapper > :not(.' + href + ')').hide();
      $('.wrapper > .' + href + '').slice(0,3).show();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseover(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
      });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseout(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").each(function() {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    $('#perspectives .perspectiveReadurl', '#page_perspectives .perspectiveReadurl').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.Whitepapers').slice(0,4).show();
    perspective_type();
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```css
.views-row{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_perspectives">
  <div class="view view-page-perspectives view-id-page_perspectives">
    <div class="perspective-list">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="">
          <a class="Blogs" href="Blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="Case_Studies" href="Case_Studies">Case Studies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a class="Whitepapers" href="Whitepapers">Whitepapers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Case_Studies" style="display: none;">
            Case study 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you move your `style="display:none"` into `.view-row` section? or you can't modify anything on the code?

Comment: instead of show/hide I want to make display:none or display:block

Comment: show/hide will do the same.

Comment: but space is left empty.I want to display one by one

Comment: that't why i have asked one question. can you modify the html structure or it is coming dynamically?

Comment: plz check my updated [post

Comment: i can understand that. not sure why you are interested to give the answer for question `can you modify the html structure or it is coming dynamically`?

Comment: Its coming dynamically

Comment: given my answer below. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that all codes are coming dynamically and you have some height for the `views-row` section, so you want to hide `views-row` section instead of inside element section. For this you have to do the following.

1. When it is loading remove all the default style attribute for the inner elements.
2. Now it becomes all the elements is visible, so hide all the `views-row` element.
3. As per your requirement, slice the `Whitepapers` section and find it is respective parent of parent `views-row` and show it up.
4. After clicking each link, you have to find the parent of parent and show/hide element.

I have implemented the above steps in the following Snippet.

```js
(function($) {
  function perspective_type() {
    $(".perspective-list a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".perspective-list a").parent().removeClass('active');
      //$('.wrapper .page-perspective').slice(0,3).show(); /*Not sure what this line is doing. no need of this.*/
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.wrapper > :not(.' + href + ')').parent().parent().hide();
      $('.wrapper > .' + href + '').slice(0,3).parent().parent().show();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseover(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
      });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseout(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").each(function() {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    $('#perspectives .perspectiveReadurl', '#page_perspectives .perspectiveReadurl').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wrapper .page-perspective').removeAttr('style');
    $('.views-row').hide();
    $('.Whitepapers').slice(0,4).parent().parent().show();
    perspective_type();
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```css
.views-row{
height:50px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_perspectives">
  <div class="view view-page-perspectives view-id-page_perspectives">
    <div class="perspective-list">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="">
          <a class="Blogs" href="Blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="Case_Studies" href="Case_Studies">Case Studies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a class="Whitepapers" href="Whitepapers">Whitepapers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Case_Studies" style="display: none;">
            Case study 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/36sk6wd0/50/) is the fiddle version.